# An intro document to IV-GMM method

Tags: instrumental-variables, generalized-moments

I am looking for an introduction on Instrumental variable-generalized method of moments (IV-GMM), but cannot find more than the following:

https://fmwww.bc.edu/EC-C/S2014/823/EC823.S2014.nn02.slides.pdf

https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1536867X0800700402

I need an introduction, which reviews IV-GMM technique from theoretical perspective. Thanks!